# Jquery animate not "reanimating" after div closed once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have a div that uses .animate. I have the div css at:

```
 position:fixed; 
 bottom:-240px;
```

and the animate script is:

```
 $("#media").click(function () {
 $("#mediadetails").animate({height: "425px"}, 1000);
```

with a special div close:

```
 $("#mediaclose").click(function() {
 $("#mediadetails").toggle(2000);
```

The initial animate works fine-- you hit the close button and the div closes. But if you hit the media link again, it will not animate again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML.. And possibly start a fiddle.

Comment: the toggle is your problem - if you click the button two times, it will work again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `.toggle()` will just hide the element <strike>without changing the height</strike> (it does indeed change the height but also the width and opacity). The next `.animate()` will only change the height, the width and opacity will remain unchanged.

```
$('#mediaclose').click(function() {
    $('#mediadetails').animate({height: "0px"}, 2000);
});
```

Comment: OK it isn't working entirely after all. I am working with a website that uses a series of hidden divs (display:none;) that fadeIN when their respective links are clicked on. If I click on media, mediadetails will show, I can close it out by hitting close just fine. But if I click on another of the hidden divs and then on media it will not reanimate...it only reanimates when going from media to mediadetails, closing and then reopening media to mediadetails.

Comment: I would suggest to open a new topic with your new problem, including all of the relevant code